# How can I control when a camera starts moving along a curve

Tags: animation, camera, bezier-curves

I am making an animation for my senior project and although I have the actual animation done, I am having trouble with the camera paths. I have multiple camera paths set up (most of which will be following a path) and I wanted to transition between the different cameras as the animation progressed. However, when I start the animation, all the cameras start moving immediately. How can I make it so the cameras wait for a set amount of frames (time) before beginning to move?

Thank you for any help you can offer.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w7qGL3LIvcc
camera follow path
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NZRtAtAvL6k Any inquiry ask me Thankyou

Answer (score 1):

Just set keyframe where it is still, further in the timeline just before the other keyframes start moving the camera :) 
Like, if you want it to be still in half a second, place a keyframe at frame 12, and then have the other frames placed afterwards. If it is in the middle of a move section, then you need to place a keyframe where you want the camera to be still, and then place the same keyframe at the frame of how long you want the still camera to last :)

If this didn't explain your issue, please tell me, and I will try to understand the issue :)